# Maven deployment fails with conflict

Tags: maven, deployment, artifactory

I have tried the following maven commands,

```
 - mvn clean install
 - mvn clean package
 - mvn clean deploy
```

The first two got success, however, the last one (deployment) got failed with the below error message. Any suggestion on this would be helpful

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project blkmessenger-parent: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.jd.terf:blkmessenger-parent:pom:1.10.0-RC1-20190627.131740-1 from/to blkmessenger.snapshots (http://jd.artifactory.net:8081/artifactory/blkmessenger/snapshots): Failed to transfer file: http://jd.artifactory.net:8081/artifactory/blkmessenger/snapshots/com/jd/terf/blkmessenger-parent/1.10.0-RC1-SNAPSHOT/blkmessenger-parent-1.10.0-RC1-20190627.131740-1.pom. Return code is: 409, ReasonPhrase: Conflict. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons of why Artifactory will return a 409 error on deployment:

1. Deploying a Snapshots version to a repository which does not allow snapshots - Handle Snapshots is set to false
2. Deploying a Release version to a repository which does not allow releases - Handle Releases is set to false
3. [Checksum policy](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Local+Repositories#LocalRepositories-AdditionalBasicSettings) is set to "Verify against client checksums" and a client has sent a checksum, but it conflicts with the one calculated on the server then Artifactory
4. [Suppress POM Consistency](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Remote+Repositories#RemoteRepositories-Maven,Gradle,IvyandSBTRepositories) is set to true and the groupId:artifactId:version information inside the POM does not match the deployed path
5. A [user plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins) can possibly decide to return a 409 error for some reasons

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your artifactory repository allows Snapshots.

Furthermore check the pom that your groupId, artifact and version are in a correct format (version ending with "-SNAPSHOT").

Comment: I see the repository settings are enabled with "Handle Releases" & "Handle Snapshots" but not "Suppress POM Consistency Checks". After enabling it the deployment works fine. But would like to know the usage of it. Is enabling this option has any potential impact? Could you please shed some lights on this option.

Comment: Does the version number in the POM differ from the one you are trying to deploy with? Do you have any XML errors or strange symbols? Maybe you could add your POM to the question?

Comment: Would you like to see parent pom or do you also need all child pom?

Comment: Is this a multi-module project?

Comment: Yes this is a multi module project

Comment: Could you add the pom of which the deployment failed?